# Question on Upper Functions and Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu^{*}(X) < \infty $ and suppose $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a measurable and a bounded function.  Show that $g$ is an upper function.

A function $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a upper functionn if there exists a sequence of step functions, $ \{ \phi_{n} \} $ such that $$(1). \phi_{n} \uparrow g $$
$$(2). lim \int \phi_n < \infty$$. Recall the Lebesgue integral is the following defintion: $$\int \phi_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_k \mu^*(A_k)$$

Since $g$ is a bounded function, there is a $N \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $-N \leq f(x) \leq N \ \forall x \in X$. Since $g$ is a measurable function, there is a sequence of simple functions,   {\phi_n }
 such that $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \phi_n = g$ So I was going to define the sequence $\beta_n = -N \chi_{X} \wedge N \chi_{X}$. I am not sure if this sequence is correct. Is there another way to approach this problem? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: How is a step function defined in a general space $X$?

Comment: So a step function, $\phi$ is a simple function, which means $\phi = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_{k} \chi_A_{i}$ where $A_i$ is a measurable set. $\phi$ is a step function if $mu^*(A_i) < \infty$

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Latex