# How do I show this function is an upper function?

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show that $$f(n)=\begin{cases}
  \sqrt{n}&,\text{ if }x\in(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]\text{, where } n=1,2,\dotsb \\
  0 &, \text{ if }x=0
 \end{cases}$$ is an upper function and $g=-f$ is not? I am confused that the function is $f(n)$ instead of $f(x)$ (typing mistake?). It is quite strange. By the definition of the upper function, if there is a step function $f_n:I\rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $f_n\uparrow f$ almost everywhere on $I$ where $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb R$ and $\lim{n\to\infty}L\int_{I}f_n$ exsits as a real number then $f$ is an upper function. Then I define a function
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
  \sqrt{n}&,\text{ if }x\in(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]\\
  0 &, \text{ if }x\in [0.\frac{1}{n+1}]
 \end{cases}$$ where $n=1,2,\dotsb.$ Then it is clear that $f_n\in StepF([0,1])$ such that $f_n\uparrow f(n)$ almost everywhere on $[0,1].$ And
    $$L\int_{[0,1]}f_n=\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}\sqrt{n}\,dx=\sqrt{n}x\Big|_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n+1)}$$ then the l'Hospital rule yields
    $$\lim_{n\to\infty}L\int_{[0,1]}f_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n+1)}=0$$ which exists as a real number. However, it is clear that $$L\int_I f\ne 0=\lim_{n\to\infty}L\int_{[0,1]}f_n,$$ which is contradiction. Could you please give me some ideas about my mistakes or misunderstanding about the question and the definition? Thank you!

Comment: What is an "upper function"???

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615030/question-on-upper-functions-and-lebesgue-integral